# JavaME: Is it possible to run a MIDLet on a CDC configuration?

Tags: java-me, midlet, cdc

We have an application running on CLDC 1.1/MIDP 2.1, based on Midlets and lcdui.

Is it possible to run the same application on CDC 1.1 with the PBP profile ? If so, where should I even start ?

I'm using Sun WTK 3.0.

With CLDC, the starting point is a JAD file, which indicates the name of the main midlet class. What is the starting point of an application on CDC ?

Answer (score 1):

Those are two different platforms and VMs with different APIs. What you are suggesting is not possible.